# Swing vertical resizing one pane to expand other shrink (modified BorderLayout)

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

Basically i would like to have BorderLayout that will expand north section vertically and shrink center section on resize. I think it's easier to explain with pictures.

So here is situation I have now:
[image]

But when dialog is resized i would like to have buttons expand vertically and to shrink down center pane (one with tabs). Currently when dialog is resized i get this (the rest of the buttons are "hidden":

[image]

My current layout is set like this:

[image]

contentPane - BorderLayout

panelTopButtons - FlowLayout (set in north section of conentPane)

panelContent - BorderLayout (set in center section of contentPane)

So how can i achieve when dialog is resized that buttons in north section take more vertical space (and thus all are visible), and content of panelContent is shrink to fit rest of dialog contentPane space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the buttons in the `CENTER` and the tabbed pane in the `PAGE_END` of the `BorderLayout`.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it before but it seamed not to be working. With little more experimentation now it looks good.